# How to remove white spaces from within a list WITHOUT using built-in functions

Tags: python-3.x, function, whitespace

I'm trying to get this list
`spell_list =["Lumos", "Fiendfyre", "Accio", "Crucio", "Confringo"]`

to print as
`LumosFiendfyreAccioCrucioConfringo`

for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do it **without** using a built-in function

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop should do the trick

```py
output = ''
for spell in spell_list:
    output += spell
print(output)
```

In each iteration, the current spell is appended to the final string you will output.

Note: Unless it is a challenge or task, you shouldn't avoid using built-in functions